# How the ServerSOAPFaultException has to be handled? how it is different from handling SOAPFaultException?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapfault

While consuming the 3rd party WebServices I am able to handle the SOAPFaultException for example to handle sessiontimeout But Sometimes the same webservices are resulting `ServerSOAPFaultException`.

Can someone explain me how it is different from SOAPFaultException and how to deal with this exception?

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Your session has timed-out. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
             com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
               com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
      com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
               com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServerSOAPFaultException and how to read it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750446/serversoapfaultexception-and-how-to-read-it)

Comment: I have already gone through the https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751866/2830834 but  didn't get the concept.